# Access parent directory in React

Tags: css, reactjs, directory

I am trying to import bootstrap.css file into my React component, but I am getting an error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '.../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in '/Users/pavelsarygin/Desktop/programming_projects/excavate-main/excavate/client/src/components/Login/Signup'
```

Here is my folder structure:

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeQY2.png)

Can somebody please advise how to access the css file in node_modules folder from LoginForm.js component?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it like this:

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Answer (score -1):

### **Triple dots import is invalid in [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/), and you should import bootstrap in your root component**

To import any node_modules, just have relatively import like so:

```
import 'bootstrap'
```

Same when you want to import specifically some files inside that module:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

**There are also a few other ways to import your bootstrap file which can be found [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/).**